# Библиотека graphics.h

Tags: библиотеки, c++, visual-studio

Как сделать возможным использование библиотеки `graphics.h` в среде `Visual Studio 2010`?

Comment: Вам нужна старая библиотека от с++ borland 3.x под дос для студии?

Comment: точно так!
Странные преподаватели использование windows.h называют использованием язычества и ругаются страшными словами, что это WinApi. Переубедить преподавателя я не могу, так что остается вариант переписать код под grafics.h, станцевав с бубном вокруг студии...

Comment: Эээ... А как они называют использование borland-специфической библиотеки graphics?

Хотя они правы, переходите с устаревшего на прогрессивный WinRT, там у вас будет XAML в нативном коде. Но не на борландовскую фигню, которая устарела ещё когда Windows в детский садик ходила.

Могу поспорить, ваши преподаватели просто не знают WinAPI, поэтому и требуют насиловать труп.

Comment: знают они или нет - это вопрос десятый, об этом можно спорить, пока течет вода и горит огонь, Вы же понимаете, что от этого работа не сдастся =) хотя я разделяю Вашу точку зрения ;)

Comment: Если от использования той или иной графической библиотеки зависит то, зачтётся работа или нет, подумайте, нужен ли _вам_ такой вуз и не зря ли вы тратите там своё время.

Comment: @VladD, а может как раз наоборот?

Хотят посмотреть, сможет студент реализовать (переписать/перенести) функции одной среды программирования в другой?


Сможет - зачет, не сможет - будет пыль с мониторов стирать.

--

@alexelev, а Вам обязательно в VS? Если просто программу для с++ borland 3.x под дос запустить, то может на виртуалке под родным досом сгодится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некоторые фанаты сделали переходники -

- [Using the WinBGIm Graphics Library with Visual Studio 2005/2008](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/bgi/visual/)
- [в помощь студентам: graphics.h в C](https://web.archive.org/web/20141110035237/http://serrox.livejournal.com/3816.html)

Но... оно все равно неявно использует `WinApi`. Без этого под виндой сложно.

Answer (score 1):

К `Visual Studio 2010` заголовок `grafics.h` не прикрутишь, сам пытался в итоге пришел к использованию функций заголовка `windows.h`

Answer (score 1):

Сам пытался прикрутить его к студии, после недели колупаний плюнул и заставил его работать под wxDev-C++. Всё отлично пашет.

P.S. кстати не grafics.h, а graphics.h

Comment: да, Вы правы, моя очепятка =) Я тоже наталкивался на мысль об использовании DevC++